# Exceptions thrown by middleware are not being logged (.UseExceptionHandler?)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.2, kestrel-http-server

For the hell of me I can't figure this out.

I have some middleware which is throwing exceptions, i.e.

```
public class SubscriptionMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    ...

    public SubscriptionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ...)
    {
        _next = next;
        ...
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, ...)
    {           
        await _next(context); // Exception may occur here
        ...
    }
}
```

A standard mw. But when the exception occurs at the `await _next()` part, it's never logged anywhere...

My controller looks like this:

```
[ApiController]
[Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class SubscriptionsController : Controller
{
    [MiddlewareFilter(typeof(SubscriptionMiddlewareFilter))]
    [HttpPost("test")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> TestMethod(...)
    {
        ...
        return Ok(jsonResult);
    }
}
```

That middleware filter you may have noticed there looks like this (if it makes any difference):

```
public class SubscriptionMiddlewareFilter
{
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app) => app.UseMiddleware<SubscriptionMiddleware>();
}
```

Exceptions that happen in controller methods are all logged and code 500 is returned automatically. However, exceptions that return 400 (bad request), i.e. some JSON formatting issue, are all swallowed up... never logged anywhere. I was under the impression this should work automatically for `ApiController`-s.

The `Program.cs` code is pretty standard too:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
        {
            logging.ClearProviders();
            logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
        })
        .UseNLog()
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration(config =>
        {
            ...
        })
        .SuppressStatusMessages(true)
        .UseKestrel(opts =>
        {
            ...
        })              
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

What I have tried is using `UseExceptionHandler` but I don't think I'm using it right. All I could find on the web pointed to solutions which print out exception details to some HTML page or JSON output - I just need them logged, nothing else.

Here's my latest attempt, the delegate never gets invoked though:

```
var exHandlerOpts = new ExceptionHandlerOptions
{
    ExceptionHandler = ctx =>
    {

        var ex = ctx.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>().Error;

        ... log? ...

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
};

app
    .UseExceptionHandler(exHandlerOpts)
    .UseHsts()
    .UseHttpsRedirection()
    .UseAuthentication()
    .UseMvc()
    ...
```

I'm confused on this as the exception logging throughout Asp.Net Core seems to be very elegant and pretty much automatic, my background services, scoped services, controllers etc. all log them just fine. A bad request exception though... doesn't even get mentioned on the server side?

Just putting `.UseExceptionHandler()` throws me an exception:

```
'An error occurred when configuring the exception handler middleware. Either the 'ExceptionHandlingPath' or the 'ExceptionHandler' option must be set in 'UseExceptionHandler()'.'
```

Eeek! So it won't magically work out of the box, although the documentation says:

> Adds a middleware to the pipeline that will catch exceptions, **log them**, and re-execute the request in an alternate pipeline.

I want to point out that as long as the controller class is decorated with `[ApiController]`, all exceptions in the middleware used by the controller are caught and not rehtrown, e.g.

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, SubscriptionRequestData data)
{
    try
    {
        await _next(context);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // this will never happen
    }
}
```

I noticed this is the case regardless of wheter I'm calling `.UseExceptionHandler` or `.UseExceptionMiddleware`. Thus the only way to catch the exception and inspect it is within the debugger (with exception settings configured).

In my specific scenario, the bad request was caused by a a JSON formatting exception which I rather wish would be logged somewhere. Something like this:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Could not create an instance of type PushService.Abstractions.Subscription.ICriterion. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated. Path 'Criteria[0].FieldName', line 1, position 63.'

The bug in my code was easily found once I was able to read this but in production, my WebApi would not log this information. All I'd see is that there was a bad request and that's it, no further info.

Comment: These exceptions get converted into `ModelState` errors ([source](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/2.2/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ModelBinding/Binders/BodyModelBinder.cs#L188)), so you're not going to be able to catch them yourself. I think your only sensible option is to interrogate `ModelState` and log the errors accordingly.

Comment: @Kirk you're right, that pretty much answers the question then. There seem to be basically different policies for different things. You may post an answer if you wish and I'll accept it.